# REST issue Sharepoint 2013

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm using the REST interface for Sharepoint 2013 to retrieve some elements from a list.

Here is my function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getAllProgramName(){
        // Getting our list items
        var call = $.ajax({
            url: "https://aleinternational.sharepoint.com/sites/CapexRequest/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Program')/items?$filter=Year eq '2015'&$select=Program_x0020_name",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        });
        call.done(function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
            alert('success'+jqXHR.responseText);
        });
        call.fail(function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
            alert('success'+jqXHR.responseText);
        });
    }
</script>
```

But I always get a correlation ID error when I have two operations in the url (here, I have $select and $filter).
If I remove the $filter or the $select operation, it works fine.

Do you guys have any idea?
Thanks !

Comment: Check your year column type in list
OR
how are you making your rest query
I think use some tool like **caml designer**

Comment: You could try to use the "Advanced REST Client" chrome plugin to help you to 'debug' the problem. [Here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) is the download link.

Answer (score 0):

@user3206787 I recently wrote one REST code.

With regards to your query i changed the sequence of $filter and $select. Still query returns the results. so sequence of $select and $ filter wont matter.

```
 url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Exit%20Test%20Questions')/Items?$filter=ExitTest/Id eq "+$scope.selectedTest.Id+"&$select=Title,Answer,Id,QuestionType,ExitTest/Id&$expand=ExitTest/Id", 


/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Exit%20Test%20Questions')/Items?$select=Title,Answer,Id,QuestionType,ExitTest/Id&$expand=ExitTest/Id&$filter=ExitTest/Id eq "+$scope.selectedTest.Id
```

Please check two things :-

1. Pass year as int:2015 instead of as string:'2015'
2. In select first try fetching basic Title column [$select=Title] and
   then if it is fetching required result then go for complex column
   name like Program_x0020_name.